# how to remove selectbox selected option bg shadow?

Tags: jquery, css

I am simply created selectbox add and remove using jquery.Its working fine what i am expected but my problem is when click on option and click outside that option's background shadow not disappear.Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ff5Lp0gv/27/. Even i tried below code

```
select {
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 #000;
}
```

But no use!.

How to fix this?

Comment: If I get your question correctly, you ask how to change selectfield option background-color which indicates the selected element? As long as you work with a real select field, and not a JavaScript based replacement, you can't. But what you could do in your case is removing the selection when focusing another element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the selected attribute from the selected option in the change event of the select:

```
$('#SelectFeatures').find('option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ff5Lp0gv/29/

If you want to loose the selection when clicking outside, try using the code inside the focusout event.